# Could not send password reset link in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I cannot send the password reset link in the email with the error:

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required

I have followed [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dabJ03-IpaQ) but still I could not solve the problem.

**.env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=52ca17394c74f6
MAIL_PASSWORD=e89831236006c1
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => 'hello@example.com',
        'name' => 'Example',
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
];
```

Comment: It looks like an issue with mailtrap.io rather than Laravel itself.

Comment: okey, do you have any other method to reset the password here??

Comment: I have tried to change the mail.php:return array(
  "driver" => "smtp",
  "host" => "smtp.mailtrap.io",
  "port" => 2525,
  "from" => array(
      "address" => "from@example.com",
      "name" => "Example"
  ),
  "username" => "52ca17394c74f6",
  "password" => "e89831236006c1",
  "sendmail" => "/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs",
  "pretend" => false
); but couldnot solve the problem.

Comment: @sangay the mailtrap host is `smtp.mailtrap.io` and that's not what your .env file has. Also when you make changes to .env file, you should clear the config since it might be cached. You can clear it by running `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @Sandeesh thank you so much it work for me

Comment: @sangay np i'll add that as an answer in case others stumble on this same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mailtrap host is smtp.mailtrap.io and that's not what your .env file has. Also when you make changes to .env file, you should clear the config since it might be cached. You can clear it by running `php artisan config:clear`